# What is the best practice to handle related constant strings in Java?

Tags: java, string, constants, final-class

Let us assume that I have to handle several constant strings that are closely related, for example types of messages ("ID1", "ID2", "ID3"). Currently I use a final class that only has public static final definitions:

```
public final class MessageType {
   public static final String ID1 = "ID1";
   public static final String ID2 = "ID2";
   public static final String ID3 = "ID3";
}
```

In the various classes I access the strings as `MessageType.ID<X>`.
Is this the best way to handle this scenario or the best practice is different?
Thanks.

Comment: Enums were bade for this sort of thing, no?

Comment: but what if my id is long and with spaces?

Comment: Underscores would replace the spaces.

Comment: [Enum Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach has one big drawback: There's no decent way to transform a String such as `"ID1"` back to `MessageType.ID1`.

The common approach here is to use an `enum`:

```
public enum MessageType {
  ID1,
  ID2,
  ID3
}
```

Their String representation is `MessageType.ID1.name()`. You can transform the name back to a constant by iterating over `MessageType.values()`.

This has the limitation that the constants need to be valid regarding the java syntax. Enums are basically a list of instances of that enum class. Writing down the constant names is essentially a call to a constructor. That means you can assign values to each instance:

```
public enum MessageType {
  ID1("ID 1"), //calls the constructor
  ID2("something else with spaces");

  private final String text; //field

  MessageType(String t) { //the constructor
    this.text = t;
  }

  //and the lookup:
  static MessageType getByText(String text) {
    for(MessageType t:values()) {
      if(t.text.equals(text)) {
        return t;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  public String getText() {
    return text;
  }
}
```

You can now access these longer Strings using `MessageType.ID2.text`. Calling `MessageType.getByText("ID 1")` will return `MessageType.ID1`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The example is not very relevant, but what if I have to store strings with spaces or special characters?

Comment: Note that instance fields in enum types (like the `text` field) are not implicitly `final`. That means that with your sample code someone could write `MessageType.ID1.text = "Hello World";`. Please always make your instance fields in enum types final like this: `public final String text;`

Comment: @ThomasKläger agreed, edited the code. I used a non-final public field for simplicity, changed it to a private final field with a getter.